# TYPO3 registration page for frontend user

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I have a question. I never used to work with TYPO3. Our company use it for vacation days, but they don't have registration page and I don't understand how to add the registration page. I saw some plugins for TYPO3 and I tried to see how it works but I have some problems. If someone can give me an advice how to make a normal page for registration with TYPO3 I will appreciate it a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: don't even consider using out-of-date versions of TYPO3 like (TYPO3 7 or TYPO3 6). especially for TYPO3 beginner a no go.

Comment: We have Typo 8.7.31. Is it very complicated to create a registration page? The project is almost done but people can't create an account by themselves. The admin has always to create an account

Comment: `EXT:femanager` good choice for creating registration form. Did you checked one? See https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/femanager/

Comment: This one I didn't try. Would you like to help me with installation please?

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation at least: https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/6.1/en-us/Installation/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

[EXT:femanager](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/femanager/) was suggested in the comments already. I can recommend this extension too. [EXT:sf_register](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sf_register/) is also a very good choice. I definitely can't recommend EXT:sr_feuser_register.

To get started you need to download the extension from the TYPO3 Extension Repository. This can be done in the [TYPO3 Extension Manager](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtensionManager/Index.html). If your installation is composer based, you need to require the extensions in your root composer.json.

After the installation please follow the documentation of the extensions:

- [Documentation EXT:femanager](https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/5.4/en-us/Installation/Index.html)
- [Documentation EXT:sf_register](https://docs.typo3.org/p/evoweb/sf-register/8.8/en-us/Administration/Index.html)

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you very much. I have the same plugin but I want to have a page where people can go by themselves and create a new account. Because with this plugin only admins can create a new account for someone?

Comment: Both extensions are for Frontend Registration, not for backend adminitrators! They both offer a plugin which you can place on a frontend site. Please read the documentation carefully. It's all explained there.

Comment: Right now I read how it works. Do you have 10-15min for me? Maybe we can have a call. Because the typo3 doesn't have a backup and maybe you can help me :) please :) to be honest I don't know how to reinstall typo3 if something will be going wrong that's why I'm a little scared

Comment: Sorry, but no. If you need professional help, please check the [Professional Services Listing](https://typo3.com/partners/professional-service-listing/).